# Will javascript private members in classes cause a huge memory overhead?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, fields of an object are always "public":

```
function Test() {
  this.x_ = 15;
}
Test.prototype = {
  getPublicX: function() {
    return this.x_;
  }
};
new Test().getPublicX();       // using the getter
new Test().x_;                 // bypassing the getter
```

but you can simulate a "private" field by using a local variable, and using a closure as the getter:

```
function Test() {
  var x = 15;
  this.getPrivateX = function() {
    return x;
  };
}
new Test().getPrivateX();       // using the getter
// ... no way to access x directly: it's a local variable out of scope
```

One difference is that with the "public" approach, each instance's getter is the same function object:

```
console.assert(t1.getPublicX === t2.getPublicX);
```

whereas with the "private" approach, each instance's getter is a distinct function object:

```
console.assert(t1.getPrivateX != t2.getPrivateX);
```

I'm curious about the memory usage of this approach. Since each instance has a separate `getPrivateX`, will this cause a huge memory overhead if I create, say, 10k instances?

A performance test on creating instances of classes with private and public members:

[Jsperf](http://jsperf.com/private-public-member)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204526/understanding-javascript-closures-and-memory-usage

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239533/javascript-private-methods-what-is-the-memory-impact?rq=1

Comment: Both the public and private approaches are linear - `O(n)` - in resource consumption (just with different `C`). Since it is ultimately an implementation detail, the only way to known if it "[uses too] much memory overhead" is to run some tests. For an object that is *known* to have 10k+ (100k+?) instances, I would opt for the prototype-only method first; this being *my own unverified* "performance" imposition. But again, it's all linear growth.

Comment: (I gave an up-vote, because I think it would be nice to have an answer with *empirical evidence* from the *different ECMAScript implementations*.)

Comment: @ruakh you're right about the naming thing, but this is the only way to expose a private member.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it would create memory overhead. In the public case your function belongs to the `prototype` not to the instance, which means there is only one instance, unless you specifically give a specific object it's own instance of that function. In the private case the function belongs to the instance which means that you need to perform memory management.

What I mean by this is the following:

```
var t1 = new Test();
t1.getPublicX = function () {
    return true;
}

var t2 = new Test();

t1.getPublicX(); // Returns true
t2.getPublicX(); // Returns 15
```

So you can end up in the same situation with public members as well. In general the answer to your question is: ***Yes there is a memory overhead when instantiating a large number of objects.***

I should also add that the notion of `public` and `private` in `javascript` is not at all the same as in `C++`. In `C++` private encapsulates the member for access only from within the class, which in `javascript` you can still access the member from anywhere.

And still after running a short test the overhead is in fact insignificant. The tab takes 40mb more (with google loaded) than without it as show in the screenshot below:

[image]

[Link to full size image.](http://tinypic.com/r/9kv2q1/6)